# Не переведен бейджик в отслеживаемых знаках

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Заметил еще небольшой пропуск в переводе сайта.
В окне выбора отслеживаемого знака рекомендуемый знак помечен зеленым беджиком.

На беджике написано `recommended`. Надо бы на `рекомендуемый` исправить...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже исправлено или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Единственная [строка "recommended" в Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262994?key=0aef2da721f0ab14676f8d6ffb9e7e8c) уже переведена как "рекомендовано". Либо это она, но не используется должным образом, либо нужной строки вообще нет в системе.

Answer (score 2):

Исправить на `рекомендуется`.​